# How to convert from command line to bash script?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a chain of commands that can execute all at once, however I wish to put it inside of a bash script. The problem is that I have no clue how to. My command is like so:

`/usr/bin/sort -n db | /usr/bin/awk -F: '{print $1; print $2}' | db5.1_load -T -t hash newdb`

How can I convert the above into a bash script?

Comment: Stick it in a file, `chmod +x` ?

Comment: I tried this, and it did not work.

Comment: What kind of errors did you get, then?

Comment: I forgot to include the path to sort and awk. My apologies guys.

Comment: You may be missing the Unix shebang on the first line, see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should normally be as simple as putting the shell command into a text file, and putting the [Unix shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on the first line of the file, which defines which program to use to run the script (in this case, `/bin/bash`). So this would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/sort -n db | /usr/bin/awk -F: '{print $1; print $2}' | db5.1_load -T -t hash newdb
```

Comment: Just be aware that if you execute that script on Solaris then it will fail because /usr/bin/awk on Solaris is old, broken awk which does not support the -F option. On Solaris us /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk.